# Composition of distance and continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let (M, $d$) a metric space and $h$ a continuous function $h : \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+$.
We suppose that :

(i) $h(0) = 0$ ;

(ii) $h$ is differentiable on $]0, +\infty[$ ;

(iii) $h'(x)> 0$ on $]0, +\infty[$ ;

(iv) and $h'$ is decreasing on $]0, +\infty[$.

Show that $f = h ∘ d$ is also a distance on M.

I struggle to show the triangular inequality $f(x,y) \leq f(x,z) + f(z,y)$. I was told to use mean value theorem.

I have a few attempts : suppose we have $y \leq x$, we would have a $c \in ]y,x[$ such that $h(x)-h(y)=h'(c)(x-y)\leq h'(y)(x-y)$, we also have an $u \in ]0,y[$ such that $h(y)-h(0)=h(y)=h'(u)y$. (I think we want to show that $h(x+y) \leq h(x) + h(y)$).

Comment: *Hint:* $h$ is concave and therefore subadditive.

Comment: Yes thank you, it was my first idea but that mean value theorem hint made me change direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$ because $d$ is a distance. $h'$ is decreasing so h is concave which means $h(d(x,y)) \leq h(d(x,z) + d(z,y)) \leq h(d(x,z)) + h(d(z,y))$